# ReactMapGL (mapbox) drag event handler doesn't move the map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to build a component for a personal project using mapbox. I can paint the map, but when it comes to move the map using the event handler onviewportchange it doesnt let drag the map around, nor I can zoom in. Also the text isnt displayed and i cant rightclick on the browser to check the console (to check if the text was displayed somewhere there). Also when I tried to display some data also didn't show up (not in the code).

I tried to use useState to change the viewport using a setViewport so i can move around the map.

```
// src/App.js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';


function App() {
  
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 41.396255,
    longitude: 2.189521,
    zoom: 12,
    width:"60vw",
    height:"60vh"
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}>
      <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
      onViewPortChange={viewport => {setViewport(viewport)}}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    >
     INFOHERE
  </ReactMapGL>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue with the same setup you did:
instead of using < ReactMapGl /> ReactMapGl docs tell us to use:

```
import Map from 'react-map-gl';
<Map/>
```

Additionally, if you do

```
 {...viewport}
```

it blocks you from moving it around, if you use:

```
initialViewState={viewport}
```

you'll get behavior as you expected